# Destroying Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

How do I delete the button 'Subject Lines'? Aka. 'Row'

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import*
import tkinter

def destroy():
    row.destroy()

master = Tk()
row = tkinter.Button(master, text="Subject Lines", command=destroy).grid(row=4,column=0, pady=6)
Button(master, text='Allocation', command=allocation).grid(row=4,column=2, pady=6)
print("Start")
Label(master, text="Create subject rows or allocate teachers to subjects").grid(row=0)
mainloop()
```

Comment: `row` is `None`, the result of calling `.grid()` on the Button, rather than the Button itself.  Do the `.grid()` as a separate statement, and `row.destroy()` should work.

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks.

Comment: Ive added an answer, would appreciate marking as correct answer